# Какое нормальное АПИ можно использовать для построения ЖД маршрутов

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

Ищу апи, где поддерживается построение маршрутов между двумя точками на жд пути. Яндекс, 2Гис и прочие конторы не поддерживают это

Comment: Посмотри тут https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417117/seeking-api-for-rail-route-distance